# Exclude folders on publish project using "dnu publish"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

How can I exclude folders from wwwroot using "dnu publish" command.

Example: in my project exists many folders

I need exclude **wwwroot/lib** and **wwwroot/source**.

I´m using clr 1.0.0-beta7-12302

Answer (score 3):

The `wwwroot` folder is treated differently. It is called a *webroot*. The content in this folder doesn't go through globbing during publish [(see here)](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling/Publish/PublishProject.cs#L637). It is recommended that source code and output are put out of the *webroot*.

Do you have scenario that you have to store source codes and binaries in this folder?

Comment: Hi Troy, I would say [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32790748/551030) of Joe is a perfect scenario

Comment: I agree with Andrew, there is a lot of cruft below wwwroot/lib that we would rather not publish to production, but it makes sense for wwwroot/lib to be there during development. So I think the asp.net team should either provide some guidance on how to manage the client dependencies in dev vs production or provide a way to exclude specific folders from below wwwroot when publishing

Answer (score 2):

Within the `Project.json` file it looks like you can specify which files you would like to exclude when publishing using the `publishExclude` property in the `sources` section. https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file#sources

Answer (score 1):

I too was looking for a way to exclude the `wwwroot/lib` directory from being published and I came across [this post from Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ControlHowYourBowerPackagesAreInstalledWithAGulpfileInASPNET5.aspx). In the post he shows how to change the storage location of bower components (ex. from `wwwroot/lib` to `/bower_components`).

For me this removed the `wwwroot/lib` directory, so these libraries are no longer published. I just thought I would throw this here in case someone may be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

[MS dropped support for `bower_components` and `node_modules` exclusion](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/94) in **.NET Core 1.0 RTM**. The best I was able to achieve was just to exclude the `/src` folders so the publish size could be reduced.

#### Project.json (*Excluding Bower Components SRC files*)

```
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
        "wwwroot",
        "Views",
        "Areas/**/Views/**",
        "appsettings.json",
        "web.config"
    ],
    "exclude": [ "wwwroot/**/src/**" ]
}
```