# Exclude non-minified files from publish in `project.json` with ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, publish

I am trying to find a proper configuration for the `publishOptions` inside `project.json` (ASP.NET Core 1.0 / Full Framework) so that non-minified files are not published.

Official documetation doesn't help much: [project.json reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#publishoptions).

Searching for globbing patterns, and finding some artilcles with `gulp` examples,  I came up with this `wwwroot/js/**/*!(*.min.js)`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is my syntax wrong? Or, it's just that `project.json` and `dotnet publish` don't support this syntax?

```
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
        "wwwroot",
        "Views",
        "Areas/**/Views",
        "appsettings.json",
        "web.config"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot/lib",
        "wwwroot/js/**/*!(*.min.js)",
        "wwwroot/css/*.less",
        "wwwroot/_references.js"
    ],
    "includeFiles": [],
    "excludeFiles": []
},
```

Comment: You shouldn't put them there in the first place anyways but use gulp to clear the wwwroot folder and copy over the correct files, then do the actual deployment. The default templates in VS already offer min and non-min tasks. Using build servers you can call a specific task which first clears the folder, then runs the min scripts which copy and minify the scripts into the wwwroot folder and then run the publishing/deployment script

Comment: @Tseng in order to use js files at dev time they still have to live below wwwroot right? otherwise you would have to run a task after every edit if they live somewhere else. ie the default location is wwwroot/lib for bower components so they can be used directly from there. I think that minified files should be copied into a different sub folder below wwwroot and then all the other dev folders below wwwroot can be excluded from publish.

Comment: That's what bothers me too. The default structure hints at keeping both development and production files under `wwwroot`. Probably a better site structure would be the answer. Move `/lib` and all developemnt files outside `wwwroot` and have some `gulp watch` tasks do the dirty work. I wouldn't mind a "solution" through the exclude configuration though. Too lazy to change current project.

Comment: @JoeAudette: Nope. When you use bower or npm within visual studio, they will pull their dependencies into `bower_modules` and `node_modules` directions in your project roots. The usual workflow is to setup an gulp or grunt task (depends on which you use/favor) and copy the required files (either minimized or non-minimized, for which by default to different tasks exist) into i.e. wwwroot/lib/**. You can then bind specific tasks to certain events like "before build" and "after build". On top of that, you can also enable watch mode that will automatically minify/copy over your own files on change

Comment: Look at the `gulpfile.js` on a fresh ASP.NET Core MVC template (not webapi one, it doesn't come with js files and no gulp config). It's specifically made for having the same workflow in VS as you would have on a build server. And you'd could add tasks that are only executed by your build server on publish/deploy (which do not correspond to one of the VS related events). Last but not least, you can put the scripts into the project.json too to trigger certain gulp tasks on pre/post publish

Comment: Litte update. My bad, I forgot they removed gulpfile.js from default template as it comes with it's own minifier now. I'll try to put in a small sample using gulp tasks

Comment: also notice that the .bowerrc file in the default vs web app template puts files in wwwroot/lib not in bower_modules

Comment: you cannot reference script or css files unless they are below wwwroot so it makes sense to have both dev version and minified/combined production stuff below wwwroot

Comment: if you were to use bower_modules folder outside of wwwroot, you will see it is a problem when you pull in something big like ckeditor and it nearly chokes vs on the task when you try to make it copy those files to a different folder. much easier workflow if that kind of processing is only needed for pre-publish

Comment: see also my answer on this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783158/why-are-bower-components-installed-in-wwwroot/32790748#32790748

Comment: @JoeAudette: That's why I usually limit task to only copy the files required for my scenario rather than copy the whole folder content. Why the hastle? I usually don't want to deploy 50 MB worth of JavaScript with each deployment, because bower/npm put the whole packages including the developer files into it and usually don't want the non-minifed/*.ts files be inside wwwroot which is a public folder

Comment: I agree, that is why I like to leave out wwwroot/lib from publishing but I still prefer to use that location for dev purposes. I really see no reason to store js or css in a place where the files cannot be referenced or used. I previously asked Damien Edwards about the ability to exclude specific sub folders below wwwroot from publishing, it did not work in rc2 and I was told it was a bug and it should work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The typical workflow for JavaScript files/libraries management is to use gulp or grunt tasks to copy over the necessary files into the `wwwroot` folder which may happen on certain events (prebuild, postbuild, project open, clean).

In the latest tooling, the default MVC doesn't include gulpfile.js anymore as the most common usage was to minify and bundle js files, even when no external libraries were used so gulp may be a bit overwhelming for new users.

But it can easily be brought back, when you right-click the `bundleconfig.json` file in the solution explorer and choose "Bundler & Minifier" > "Convert to Gulp".

This creates a `gulpfile.js` and `package.json` (nodejs dependencies) in the root of your project and adds npm folder to the "Dependencies" section of Solution Explorer. When you watch in the Windows Explorer, you'll see a `node_modules` folder in the project root folder. That's where npm will download all packages and it's dependencies.

The generated `gulpfile.js` looks like this and has a few predefined tasks. i won't use this file as example, as it is strongly based on the `bundleconfig.json` and it's structure and use my `gulpfile.json` which used to be shipped with older templates.

```
"use strict";

var gulp = require("gulp"),
    rimraf = require("rimraf"),
    concat = require("gulp-concat"),
    cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin"),
    uglify = require("gulp-uglify");

var webroot = "./wwwroot/";

var paths = {
    app: webroot + "app/",
    libs: webroot + "lib/",
    js: webroot + "js/**/*.js",
    minJs: webroot + "js/**/*.min.js",
    css: webroot + "css/**/*.css",
    minCss: webroot + "css/**/*.min.css",
    concatJsDest: webroot + "js/app.min.js",
    concatCssDest: webroot + "css/app.min.css"
};

gulp.task("clean:js", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatJsDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean:libs", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.libs, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean:css", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatCssDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean", ["clean:js", "clean:css", "clean:libs"]);

gulp.task("min:js", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.js, "!" + paths.minJs], { base: "." })
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min:css", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.css, "!" + paths.minCss])
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatCssDest))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min", ["min:js", "min:css"]);

gulp.task("libs", function (cb) {
    gulp.src([
        'bootstrap/**/*.js',
        'bootstrap/**/*.css',
        'jquery/**/*.js`, // we can also limit this to `jquery/dist/**/*.js to only include distribution files
        'jquery/**/*.css'
    ], {
        cwd: "node_modules/**"
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.libs));
});

gulp.task("app", function (cb) {
    gulp.src([
        'app/**.js'
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.app));
});

gulp.task("default", ['clean', 'libs']);
```

It looks more complicated than it actually is. There are several minizier tasks (`min:js`, `min:css`) and one general minifier task `min` which just runs all others in sequence.

A clean task which deletes the output file(s) from `wwwroot`. When converting from the template, it deletes only the default `wwwroot/js/site.min.js` file.

Since there are no javascript libraries used in the default template, except of what's inside the `wwwroot/lib` folder already the packages are not handled that way.

So first thing you may want is to grab bootstrap and jquery from npm rather than the static versions provided by the template. So we add the dependencies to the `package.json`.

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "jquery": "2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.8.11",
    "gulp-concat": "2.5.2",
    "gulp-cssmin": "0.1.7",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.2.0",
    "rimraf": "2.2.8"
  }
}
```

The `libs` task from the `gulpfile.js` above for example will copy over all required files of a package to `wwwroot`. I said required, because in the packages there are often unbundled files for debugging and stuff, which we usually don't want inside `wwwroot` (they can grow quite big).

```
gulp.task("libs", function (cb) {
    gulp.src([
        'bootstrap/**/*.js',
        'bootstrap/**/*.css'
    ], {
        cwd: "node_modules/**"
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.libs));
});
```

It will look for all `*.js` and `*.css` files within the bootstrap folder in `node_modules` folder and copy them over to `path.libs` which is configured as `wwwroot/lib/`.

The `app` task does the same for our own code. `clean` clears the folders and (i.e. before switching from debug to release build or before publishing).

Finally you can bind the tasks to certain VS Events. You need to open the "Task Runner Explorer" View (View > Other Window > Task Runner Explorer). There you can choose a task and right-click it, then "Binding" and choose one of the binding (Before Build, After Build, Clean, Projct Open). They are pretty self explaining, "Clean" means when you do "Build > Clean Solution".

Now to the publishing part. You can run certain command, when you publish your application (either via dotnet or Visual Studio).

In the `project.json` there is a scripts section for this.

```
"scripts": {
  "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min", "gulp libs" ],
  "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
}
```

Each of the entries "prepublish" is one command to be executed. In this example, before the publishing begins, `npm install` will be executed first in order to restore all `npm` dependencies. Then `bower install` to install the dependencies managed by bower (remove it if you don't use bower and do all via npm).

The next three commands are the interesting ones, they will execute gulp tasks. We can also simplify this by adding a "publish" task.

```
gulp.task("publish", ['clean', 'libs', 'min']);

"scripts": {
  "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp publish" ],
  "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
}
```

This will copy all the necessary files for publishment into the wwwroot folder, publish the files and then call the "postpublish" scripts.

That's a rough introduction in gulp. It's has a learning curve, but once you get it working it imrpoves the overall workflow.

What's not covered here is to add a `watch` task which may look into a certain folder (I usually use `app` folder in the project root) and when any file changes there run the `app` task, so the our code gets minifed and copied over to `wwwroot` and is available when we debug it.

Comment: Although, all this info was not exactly what I was looking for, I really appreciate the effort you put in your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A simple alternative is:

1. Rename unminified source to *.debug.js and *.debug.css
2. They are now easier to exclude:

`"publishOptions": {
        "include": [
            "wwwroot"
        ],
        "exclude": [
            "wwwroot/**/*.debug.*"
        ]
    }`

IMHO unminified source should stick out and look abnormal. It is more deserving of a file name wart than minified code.

This also brings the build output files into line with the rest of the .Net build configuration. It makes it clear that your debug versions may well include extra logging and debug utilities and that its not for production.