# Foldertype of wwwroot from ASP.NET Core and use it in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, wwwroot

I manage all my plugins in my ASP.NET MVC application with bower.

**The problem:**
Bower works great, but when it installs the plugins, I don't see them in my solution. I'd have to show all files (which is not updated automatically) and then include them, which then causes problems when I update them again...

**What I want:** 
ASP.NET Core projects have a special folder for the wwwroot, which automatically makes the file visible in the solution, when it's created e.g. in the File Explorer.

**What I tried:**
Edit the `.csproj` to `'lablabla\bower_components\**` This only included the files at startup and some changes in the project replaced the `**`([Source](http://www.mattburkedev.com/automatically-include-all-files-in-folder-in-visual-studio/)).

[image]

Comment: You probably know this discussion (months ago), but let it be here for the record: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783158/why-are-bower-components-installed-in-wwwroot/32790748#32790748 and for anyone else that is trying to come up with a decision about this one.

Comment: No, I didn't know that. Still doesn't answer what kind of folder the wwwroot is and if I can use it in MVC 5. However I edit my question so it says that in the title too

Comment: The `wwwroot` folder is just s special folder in the world of .Net Core and no, you can't have this in MVC5. It may be possible with some sort of addon though.

Comment: A plugin would be fine too :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it yet, but you can try to use "Post Build" event to copy this folder.

Click on Project->Properties->Build Events->Post Build

And try to use "copy" or "xcopy" using keywords like $(SolutionDir) and $(TargetDir) or the absolute paths

An example:

```
xcopy "$(SolutionDir)xxxxx\bower_components" "$(TargetDir)\" /S /Y
```

Another example:

```
xcopy "c:\MyProject\xxx\bower_components" "c:\MyOtherProject\wwwroot\" /S /Y
```