# ASP.NET Core + Foundation 6 how correctly configuration gulp configuration file?

Tags: gulp, zurb-foundation-6, asp.net-core-webapi

For my test web application I using Foundation 6. But I can't understand how correctly configuration gulp configuration file

I found this example gulpfile

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

var sassPaths = [
  'lib/foundation-sites/scss',
  'lib/motion-ui/src',
  '../../lib/scss'
];

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('../../lib/scss/app.scss')
      .pipe($.sass({
          includePaths: sassPaths
      })
        .on('error', $.sass.logError))
      .pipe($.autoprefixer({
          browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 9']
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('../../inc/css'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass'], function () {
    gulp.watch(['../../lib/scss/**/*.scss'], ['sass']);
});
```

But he do not work. And how I understand it will be little, also need js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is content of my gulpfile.js. See "sass" task.

```
/// <binding Clean='clean' />
"use strict";

var gulp = require("gulp"),
    rimraf = require("rimraf"),
    concat = require("gulp-concat"),
    cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin"),
    uglify = require("gulp-uglify"),
    sass = require("gulp-sass"),
    debug = require("gulp-debug");

    //sass = require("gulp-sass"),
    //debug = require('gulp-debug'),
//mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');
//* see https://github.com/mauricedb/gulp-main-bower-files if decide to concat libs into one **//
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783158/why-are-bower-components-installed-in-wwwroot/32790748#32790748

var webroot = "./wwwroot/";

var paths = {
    js: webroot + "js/**/*.js",
    minJs: webroot + "js/**/*.min.js",
    css: webroot + "css/**/*.css",
    minCss: webroot + "css/**/*.min.css",
    concatJsDest: webroot + "js/site.min.js",
    concatCssDest: webroot + "css/site.min.css"
};

gulp.task("clean:js", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatJsDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean:css", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatCssDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean", ["clean:js", "clean:css"]);

gulp.task("min:js", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.js, "!" + paths.minJs], { base: "." })
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min:css", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.css, "!" + paths.minCss])
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatCssDest))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min", ["min:js", "min:css"]);

// where to find sass code
paths.sassSource = webroot + "scss/**/*.scss";

// where to output compiled CSS code
paths.cssOutput = webroot + "css/";

// where to find bower resources
paths.bower_components = webroot + "lib/"

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.sassSource)
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: [
                paths.bower_components + 'foundation-sites/scss',
                paths.bower_components + 'motion-ui/src'
            ]
        }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cssOutput));
});
```